# ComponentDidMount always changes my component state to loading which i don't want in enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have componentDidMount lifecycle method in my component which set state variable get_data_loader to true.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let writeAccess = (this.props.viewAsOriginalUser ? this.props.viewAsOriginalUser :
      isWriteable(this.props.resourceMapping["HRMS.Profile.Personal"], this.props.privileges))
    if (!writeAccess) {
      this.state.column_names.splice(-1, 1)
    }
    this.setState({
      get_data_loader: true, 
      allVisa: this.props.coc['visa'],
      writeAccess: writeAccess,
    });
    this.apiCall();
  }
```

So in my test file if I print wrapper.html() then it only shows spinner code because the data_loader variable of the state is true because of the call to componentDidMount

So is there any way I can change get_data_loader to false in the componentDidMount from the test file or is there any way I can stop shallow or mount from calling componentDidMount so it does not manipulate the state?

I have tried

```
console.log(wrapper.state('get_data_loader'))
wrapper.setState({ get_data_loader: false });
wrapper.update()
console.log(wrapper.html())
```

But its still printing the spinner code only.

[Update]

```
my test file:

import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import PersonalProfile from '../../components/Profile/Tabs/Personal';
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../../redux/configureStore";
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import { PROFILE_QUERY } from "../../utils/Queries";


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
const store = configureStore();
jest.mock('../../utils/client.js', () => {
    return {
      return_string:""
    };
  });

describe('Personal Profile', () => {
  
  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider>
        <PersonalProfile store={store}/>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    
    console.log(wrapper.state('get_data_loader'))
    wrapper.setState({ get_data_loader: false });
    wrapper.update()
    console.log(wrapper.html())
  });
});
```

In my render I have something like this :

```
{this.state.get_data_loader ? (
          <Spinner
            style={{ marginLeft: "50%", marginTop: "10%" }}
            animation="border"
          />
        ) : ( render the component )}
```

Comment: Please provide the full test you wrote so far + the method in component who sets the loading state to false.

Comment: @yaya done. can you review now?

Comment: please also add the render function on your component.

Comment: @yaya Added render function. In that, if get_data_loader is false then only I am rendering the actual component. So want some way to set it false from the test file. ComponentDidMount set it to true and the apical set it again to false but i am not amking an api call so want some other way.

Comment: 1. As someone answered, you can use async test and wait some seconds to make sure it's loaded. 2. Another way is to setstate manually. Also don't forget that you also need to mock the apiCall to get the data loaded, because it's async and if you don't want to wait, you should mock it. The question is why setState doesn't work for you? (i tested your code and it worked for me, but i tested component directly without redux).  so maybe it's because of redux as your another question. You're calling setState on redux cintainer, not the component.

Comment: @yaya that was the case. I was calling set state on redux, not my actual component. Thanks for the Response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping the `expect` statement in `setTimeout`, because `setState` is an async function, and I don't know any other way to wait for it.

So, pass `jest`'s `done` as your test function's argument, wrap your `expect` in a `setTimeout`, invoke `done()` after the `expect` and inside the `setTimeout` block.